# How can I consume a drop event on an fxml element? (javafx)

Tags: java, event-handling, javafx, fxml

I have an fxml application started and I'm finding it very difficult to find relevant documentation. I want to drag a file onto my fxml application, specifically a tabpane, and get the location of the file. I am new to the fxml scene so please try your best to be simple.

**fxmlcontroller**

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML protected void onDropEndEvent(ActionEvent event) {
      System.out.println(event.toString());
   }
    @FXML protected void onDragEvent(ActionEvent event) {
      System.out.println("stuff happened");
   }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }   

}
```

**fxmldocument**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="485.0" prefWidth="577.0" style="-fx-background-color: #c4c4c4; -fx-border-radius: 0px;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="craigencdec.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <Button layoutX="458.0" layoutY="13.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="110.0" style="-fx-border-radius: 1 1 1 1; -fx-background-color: #4A4DFF; -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 10, 0, 0, 0); -fx-background-radius: 0 0 0 0;" text="Do Stuff" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="Ubuntu" size="19.0" />
         </font>
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
         </cursor>
      </Button>
      <TextField layoutX="11.0" layoutY="13.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="441.0" promptText="Enter your key here" style="-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 10, 0, 0, 0); -fx-border-radius: 0 0 0 0; -fx-background-radius: 0 0 0 0;">
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
         </cursor>
         <font>
            <Font name="Ubuntu" size="19.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <ProgressBar layoutX="332.0" layoutY="453.0" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="236.0" progress="0.06" style="-fx-background-radius: 0 0 0 0; -fx-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;">
         <opaqueInsets>
            <Insets />
         </opaqueInsets>
      </ProgressBar>
      <TabPane layoutY="69.0" onDragDetected="#onDragEvent" onDragDropped="#onDropEndEvent" prefHeight="416.0" prefWidth="325.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab closable="false" text="Encode" />
          <Tab closable="false" text="Decode" />
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="332.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="236.0" style="-fx-border-radius: 3 3 3 3; -fx-background-color: #4A4DFF; -fx-background-radius: 0 0 0 0;" text="Status" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="27.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Circle fill="WHITE" layoutX="344.0" layoutY="120.0" radius="12.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" />
      <Label alignment="TOP_LEFT" layoutX="369.0" layoutY="110.0" prefHeight="75.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="drag a file into a tab to encode or decode it" textFill="WHITE" textOverrun="CLIP" wrapText="true" />
      <LineChart layoutX="333.0" layoutY="199.0" prefHeight="243.0" prefWidth="236.0">
        <xAxis>
          <CategoryAxis side="BOTTOM" />
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
          <NumberAxis prefHeight="258.0" prefWidth="24.0" side="LEFT" />
        </yAxis>
      </LineChart>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**craigencdec**

```
package craigencdec;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author craig
 */

    public class CraigEncDec extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setTitle("Encoder/Decoder");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
    private void getBits(String fileLoc){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(""))) {
            for (int b; (b = is.read()) != -1;) {
                String s = "0000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(b);
            s = s.substring(s.length() - 8); 
            sb.append(s).append(' ');
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("This is not a valid file");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using scene builder, go to the code section and in the On Drag Dropped textfield put the name of the method in your controller that you want to handle drag events when something is dropped on this node
[image]
Then in your controller create the body of this function to be called when the drop happens

```
    @FXML private void somethingDropped(Event event) {
      System.out.println("something dropped!");
      //TODO More useful code
   }
```